# How to send data from C++ app to Matlab via UDP and plot them

Tags: c++, matlab, udp, winsock, datagram

I want to send data via UDP using Winsock from my C++ app to Matlab and plot the numbers in real time. 
For example:
I got numbers from 1 to 10, I want to send 1 from C++, recieve it in Matlab, put it on the figure (plot, bar, whatever) then send number 2, recieve it, put it on the figure and so on.

Now I can only send and recieve full 10 numbers at once and plot them after I recieve them. 
Is it possible to send single numbers as a single datagrams and recieve them separatelly?

In C++ I initialize the winsock, create a socket, complete data of the socket, bind the socket and send in loop:

```
while (i<10)
    {
        error_code = sendto(sock, (const char*)&i, 2, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr));
        if(error_code == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("\nError code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nMessage sent: %d", i);
                i++;
            }
    }
```

After all I close the socket.

In Matlab I making UDP object, open it and scan in loop. Entire function looks like this:

```
UDPsock=udp('127.0.0.1', 'LocalPort', 7766, 'Timeout', 2);
set(UDPsock, 'DatagramTerminateMode','off');
figure();
fopen(UDPsock);
while length(data) < 10
            disp('recieving')
            data = fscanf(UDPsock);
            data_num = double(data);
            plot(data_num);
end
fclose(UDPsock);
```

In Matlab debuger I see that the while loop is executed once, it collects all 10 numbers, and it closes.
I want it to be like one recieved number per one loop execution.

Comment: use the `size` parameter of [fscanf](https://mathworks.com/help/instrument/fscanf.html) to read only 1 character at a time ...

Comment: @Hoki cruel ....

Comment: It works to a certain point. I can send values no greater than 127, and no less than 0. I think it something with char representation ic c++ and in Matlab. I send an int casted to char, than i recive a char and convert it to int again in Matlab. Is there any method to recieve values greater than 127, for example 2158?